# Smart UV Project with no UV element rotation?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have a Minecraft style model that has a consistent scale of pixels in the texture that I want to be aligned with the model. "Smart UV Project" usually works well but for this model it is rotating some of the items in the UV map. I tried setting "Angle Limit" to values between 0d and 89.99d but it still is rotating elements in the UV map.
Then I tried 90d but it seems to be stretching or leaving out the square parts.
[image: Bridge mesh]
Angle Limit set to 0d to 89.99d: (default is 66d)
[image: Bridge UV map]

[image: Smart UV Project Popup]

Angle Limit set to 90d: (maximum setting)

[image: Angle limit to 90d]

Answer (score 0):

Work around:

I selected all of the edges and marked them all as seams. Then I used Smart UV Project.

[image: Work around UV map and mesh]